# SSL Certificate Not Getting Refreshed

Tags: iis-7, ssl-certificate

I am trying to change the SSL Certificate for my website. I got the new certificate issued by Comodo and installed it on my web servers. My servers are running IIS7.0.

I also binded the https protocol for my websites to the new certificate. Then I deleted the old certificate(which was expired) from IIS.

Then I restarted the website
I restarted the IIS Service from an administrator command prompt.
I rebooted the servers

However, when I try to open my website in a browser, it is still giving me the expired certificate error and showing the information of the older certificate in the certificate info box.

Does anyone have an idea what might be going wrong?
Does the new SSL certificate take some time propagating across the DNS?

(My servers are hosted in AWS Cloud as EC2 instances)

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Client-side cache?

Comment: If you're in Chrome, try an incognito window.

Answer (score 0):

Open your browser and clear your cache/history.  Give the site a try first through IIS; open IIS after you've cleared your history then right click your website and click Browse.  Once that's done you can manually go to your site through your browser from then on or from IIS.

Should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you are not facing browser cache issue, you can use this powershell script to check the certificate. I also have Windows Subsystemen for Linux installed and then use openssl to check the certificate. But below is a PowerShell script i use
https://gist.github.com/jstangroome/5945820#file-get-remotesslcertificate-ps1